# How (fmap . fmap) typechecks

Tags: haskell, functor

I have been going through a article(http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/) and found the following snippet of code there:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose (f (g a)) deriving Show

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose $ (fmap . fmap) f x
```

How does actually `(fmap . fmap)` typechecks ?

Their types being:

```
(.)  :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Now from here I can see in no way in which `fmap . fmap` will typecheck ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First let's change the type variables' names to be unique:

```
(.)  :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
fmap :: Functor f => (c -> d) -> f c -> f d
fmap :: Functor g => (x -> y) -> g x -> g y
```

Now the first parameter to `.` has type `a -> b` and we supply an argument of type `(c -> d) -> (f c -> f d)`, so `a` is `c -> d` and `b` is `f c -> f d`. So so far we have:

```
(.) :: Functor f => -- Left operand
                    ((c -> d) -> (f c -> f d)) ->
                    -- Right operand
                    (r -> (c -> d)) ->
                    -- Result
                    (r -> (f c -> f d))
```

The second parameter to `.` has type `r -> a` a.k.a. `r -> (c -> d)` and the argument we give has type `(x -> y) -> (g x -> g y)`, so `r` becomes `x -> y`, `c` becomes `g x` and `d` becomes `g y`. So now we have:

```
(.)       :: (Functor f, Functor g) => -- Left operand
                                       ((g x -> g y) -> (f (g x) -> f (g y))) -> 
                                       -- Right operand
                                       ((x -> y) -> (g x -> g y)) ->
                                       -- Result
                                       (x -> y) -> f (g x) -> f (g y)
fmap.fmap :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (x -> y) -> f (g x) -> f (g y)
```

Comment: Thanks, how does the type get simplified in the last step ? `(((g x -> g y) -> (f (g x) -> f (g y)))` becomes `(x -> y)` and so are the rest of the type signature.

Comment: @Sibi In the last step all I do is remove the types of the two parameters (because they have been applied). I'm not replacing anything with anything, just removing anything before the result type.

Comment: @Sibi I changed the formatting and added comments to make this more obvious.

Comment: It helped me to use GHCi as well to query the types. If you do `:t (fmap .)` you can see how applying the left parameter gives you

`(fmap .) :: Functor f => (a1 -> a -> b) -> a1 -> f a -> f b`

which, if I'm not mistaken, is essentially equivalent to the right operand and result after applying the left operand. Great answer though, helped to change my understanding of Haskell.

Answer (score 23):

The expression `fmap . fmap` has two instances of `fmap` which can, in principle, have different types. So let's say their types are

```
fmap :: (x -> y) -> (g x -> g y)
fmap :: (u -> v) -> (f u -> f v)
```

Our job is to unify types (which amounts to coming up with equality relations between these type variables) so that the right-hand side of the first `fmap` is the same as the left-hand side of the second `fmap`. Hopefully you can see that if you set `u = g x` and `v = g y` you will end up with

```
fmap :: (  x ->   y) -> (   g x  ->    g y )
fmap :: (g x -> g y) -> (f (g x) -> f (g y))
```

Now the type of compose is

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

To make this work out, you can pick `a = x -> y` and `b = g x -> g y` and `c = f (g x) -> f (g y)` so that the type can be written

```
(.) :: ((g x -> g y) -> (f (g x) -> f (g y)))    ->    ((x -> y) -> (g x -> g y))    ->    ((x -> y) -> (f (g x) -> f (g y)))
```

which is pretty unwieldy, but it's just a specialization of the original type signature for `(.)`. Now you can check that everything matches up such that `fmap . fmap` typechecks.

---

An alternative is to approach it from the opposite direction. Let's say that you have some object that has two levels of functoriality, for example

```
>> let x = [Just "Alice", Nothing, Just "Bob"]
```

and you have some function that adds bangs to any string

```
bang :: String -> String
bang str = str ++ "!"
```

You'd like to add the bang to each of the strings in `x`. You can go from `String -> String` to `Maybe String -> Maybe String` with one level of `fmap`

```
fmap bang :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
```

and you can go to `[Maybe String] -> [Maybe String]` with another application of `fmap`

```
fmap (fmap bang) :: [Maybe String] -> [Maybe String]
```

Does that do what we want?

```
>> fmap (fmap bang) x
[Just "Alice!", Nothing, Just "Bob!"]
```

Let's write a utility function, `fmap2`, that takes any function `f` and applies `fmap` to it twice, so that we could just write `fmap2 bang x` instead. That would look like this

```
fmap2 f x = fmap (fmap f) x
```

You can certainly drop the `x` from both sides

```
fmap2 f = fmap (fmap f)
```

Now you realize that the pattern `g (h x)` is the same as `(g . h) x` so you can write

```
fmap2 f = (fmap . fmap) f
```

so you can now drop the `f` from both sides

```
fmap2 = fmap . fmap
```

which is the function you were interested in. So you see that `fmap . fmap` just takes a function, and applies `fmap` to it twice, so that it can be lifted through two levels of functoriality.

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but to me, conceptually, `fmap` represents "taking an `a -> b` and bringing it 'one level up', to `f a -> f b`".

So if I had an `a -> b`, I can `fmap` it to give me an `f a -> f b`.

If I had an `f a -> f b`, I can `fmap` it *again* to give me a `g (f a) -> g (f a)`.  Lift that `f a -> f b` function to *new heights* --- a new level.

So "fmapping" *once* lifts the function once.  fmapping *twice* lifts that lifted function...so, a double lift.

Put in the language of haskell syntax:

```
f                    ::         a   ->         b
fmap f               ::       f a   ->       f b
fmap (fmap f)        ::    g (f a)  ->    g (f b)
fmap (fmap (fmap f)) :: h (g (f a)) -> h (g (f b))
```

Notice how each successive `fmap` lifts the original `a -> b` to *another* new level.  So,

```
fmap               :: (a -> b) -> (      f a  ->        f b  )
fmap . fmap        :: (a -> b) -> (   g (f a) ->     g (f b) )
fmap . fmap . fmap :: (a -> b) -> (h (g (f a)) -> h (g (f a)))
```

Any "higher order function" that returns a function of the same arity as its input can do this.  Take `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> ([a] -> [b] -> [c])`, which takes a function taking two arguments and returns a new function taking two arguments.  We can chain `zipWith`s the same way:

```
f                   ::   a   ->   b   ->   c
zipWith f           ::  [a]  ->  [b]  ->  [c]
zipWith (zipWith f) :: [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
```

So

```
zipWith           :: (a -> b -> c) -> ( [a]  ->  [b]  ->  [c] )
zipWith . zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> ([[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]])
```

`liftA2` works pretty much the same way:

```
f                 ::      a  ->      b  ->      c
liftA2 f          ::    f a  ->    f b  ->    f c
liftA2 (liftA2 f) :: g (f a) -> g (f b) -> g (f c)
```

One rather surprising example that is put to great use in the modern implementation of the *lens* library is `traverse`:

```
f                                ::         a   -> IO          b
traverse f                       ::       f a   -> IO (      f b  )
traverse (traverse f)            ::    g (f a)  -> IO (   g (f b) )
traverse (traverse (traverse f)) :: h (g (f a)) -> IO (h (g (f b)))
```

So you can have things like:

```
traverse            :: (a -> m b) -> (   f a  -> m (   f b ))
traverse . traverse :: (a -> m b) -> (g (f a) -> m (g (f b)))
```