# Type of (map . map)

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I'm trying to understand the type of the expression `(map . map)`. Since the type of `(.)` is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` I don't understand how this works with the map function, because map takes two arguments which doesn't fit with the functions `(b -> c)` and `(a -> b)`.

Comment: Mind that `a -> b -> c` is short for `a -> (b -> c)`. In Haskell, all functions only take *one* argument.

Comment: I was thinking about that. But I couldn't decide wether it should be split up as `a -> (b -> c)` or `(a -> b) -> c`. But what you say makes sense to me now. Am I correct then if I think about it this way: if we want to consider map as a "one-parameter-function" its type is `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`, since if we supply it with its first parameter (the `(a -> b)` function) what we get in return is a function of type `([a] -> [b])`. So the types `(a -> b)` and `([a] -> [b])` correspond to the `a` and `b` in `(a -> b)` in the type for `(map . map)`?

Comment: `a -> b -> c` is the same as `a -> (b -> c)` but different that `(a -> b) -> c`

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030638/how-fmap-fmap-typechecks

Answer (score 5):

Quoting GHCI:

```
Prelude> :t map.map
map.map :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

But for map itself, type is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

which you can see as

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

So, if we have that 
`(.) :: (t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t3`

Then:

- type `t1` is `(a -> b)`
- type `t2` is `([a] -> [b])`
- type `t3` is `([[a]] -> [[b]])`

Answer (score 1):

One way I like to think of it is that `map` turns an `a -> b` into an `[a] -> [b]`, so `map . map` does it twice.  The first map turns your `a -> b` into an `[a] -> [b]`, and the second map repeats the process, turning it into an `[[a]] -> [[b]]`.

"Applying `map` to an `a -> b` turns it into an `[a] -> [b]`", so, it seems pretty pretty logical that applying `map` to an `[a] -> [b]` would turn it into an `[[a]] -> [[b]]`.  You're just applying `map` to a function twice.

Incidentally:

```
-- apply map to a function once
            map :: (a -> b) -> (  [a]   ->   [b]  )
-- apply map to a function twice
      map . map :: (a -> b) -> ( [[a]]  ->  [[b]] )
-- apply map to a function three times
map . map . map :: (a -> b) -> ([[[a]]] -> [[[b]]])
```